# writing ping results from Paramiko stdout into a txt file

Tags: python-2.7, stdout, ping, paramiko

I have a method in which I can connect to a host and ping it. I can see the ping results on the screen, but cannot write them into a file. The file is always empty. Can anyone help me in this regard?

```
def Check(self,fname):
    client = SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.connect(self.ip,22,self.username,self.password)
    ping_command = 'ping -n -c 5 '+str(self.ip)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(ping_command)
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line
    try:                        
        with open(fname,'ab') as text_file:
            text_file.wirte(stdout)
        text_file.close()        
    except IOError:
        pass        
    client.close()
```

I also tried to store stdout into a variable and then write that variable into the file and didn't get any results. I also found some topics in the site about Paramiko output, and none of them helped.

Comment: Try removing the try/except block and see if an exception gets raised

Comment: Note that you wrote `wirte` instead of `write`